# Start remote-video skype for business

Tags: lync, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I have a wpf-application which initiates a video-call to another endpoint (using the client-sdk, with UI suppression). That works fine so far - except that the remote-endpoint has to manually and explicitly activate video, so that he shares video as well.
If I use the official S4B-Client, the video starts automatically. How can I achieve the same behaviour? Or is this a known limitation?

Comment: the remote end-point is also wpf application? Are you using lync client sdk? Can you elaborate more.

Comment: Remote is a "normal" S4B-Client.
The implementation is exactly like here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh378544(v=office.14).aspx
And yes I am using the Client SDK - sorry, should have mentioned that.